# Восстановление variables в Matlab

Tags: переменные, matlab, восстановление

Есть ли способ восстановить только что удаленные переменные из Workspace (они небольшого размера)?

Результат работы SVM-классификатора был очень хорош, и на выходе получилась отличная модель, но пресловутая запись в начале каждого скрипта все испортила:

`clear all;`

Я понимаю, что скорее всего Matlab хранит все переменные в оперативной памяти, но может быть для приличия есть какие-нибудь записи и на жестком диске в этой среде?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как насчет того, чтобы разделять код на смысловые блоки? Разделение на блоки осуществляется с помощью `%%` (двойной процент). И выполнять код блоками с помощью команды: `Evaluate Current Section (Ctrl+Enter)`.

Comment: Без разбиения кода на секции не обойтись, это  да! Но даже в этом случае Workspace остается общей для хранения переменных всех исполняемых скриптов и функций и не застрахована от очистки. Интересовался этим вопросом также здесь <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37189763/recover-workspace-variable-in-matlab>. В Matlab просто нет функционала, чтобы восстановить удаленные variables.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы для этих целей использовал бы связку

```
save C:\backup_data.mat
clear all;
load C:\backup_data.mat
```